# Extracting strings between numbers

Tags: java, regex

Given the following sentence:

`My name is David and I am (1) tall, and am perhaps also a  (2) hobby programmer with (3) skills in various, and (4) things.`

Is it possible to extract the strings between the parenthetical numbers?

My ideal result would be a list:

```
A = ["tall, and am perahaps also a", "hobby programmer", 
"skills in various, and", "things"];
```

There need not be only 4 parts to the sentence, can range from 2-20.

Comment: use `String.split()`

Comment: You should give this a try first

Comment: `between the parenthetical numbers` - _things_ is not between parenthetical numbers. If you are thinking to shape the question to an easy regex, it won't happen. Edge cases will always be there. Also, what have YOU tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match these substrings with `\(\d+\)(.*?)(?=$|\(\d+\))`:

```
String s = "My name is David and I am (1) tall, and am perhaps also a (2) hobby programmer with (3) skills in various, and (4) things.";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\(\\d+\\)(.*?)(?=$|\\(\\d+\\))");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); 
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/C5yfdS)

If there can be newlines, use `Pattern.DOTALL` modifier with the regex.

The pattern matches:

- `\(\d+\)` - a digit sequence inside parentheses
- `(.*?)` - matches and captures the text up to...
- `(?=$|\(\d+\))`  - end of string or a digit sequence inside parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

You need to split the string using `(a)` as the *delimiter* where `a` is 1 or more digit.

For this you can use the *regular expression* `\(([0-9]+)\)` in the `String#split` function. Note that `\(` matches a opening parenthesis and `\)` a closing one. In code, you need to write

`str.split("\\(([0-9]+)\\)")`

where `str` is your string. Note the `\\` which passes a single backslash to the regular expression.

This produces an array of strings, which you can readily coerce into a list.

Unfortunately this will not eliminate any whitespace around `(a)`. To remedy that you could (i) adjust the regular expression to accommodate that, or (ii) trim the strings as you coerce them to a list. Note that `\s` in a regular expression matches whitespace (don't forget that you need `\\s` in Java code).

Answer (score 0):

split the string as

```
string.split("\\(([0-9]+)\\)")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little trickier than first glance suggests.
This will handle all edge cases correctly.
Each match contains the content n *Group 1*.

`(?s)\G(?:\(\d+\))*((?:(?!\(\d+\)).)+)(?:\(\d+\))*`
`"(?s)\\G(?:\\(\\d+\\))*((?:(?!\\(\\d+\\)).)+)(?:\\(\\d+\\))*"`

[Formatted and tested:](http://www.regexformat.com)

```
 (?s)                          # Modifier, dot-all
 \G                            # Start where last match ends
 (?: \( \d+ \) )*              # Consume many optional (#)
 (                             # (1 start), The content
      (?:                           # Cluster begin
           (?! \( \d+ \) )               # Assert, not (#) ahead
           .                             # Ok, grab this character
      )+                            # Cluster end, do 1 to many times
 )                             # (1 end)
 (?: \( \d+ \) )*              # Consume many optional (#)
```